# Python. Same string appearing with different encodings?

Tags: python, character-encoding

I have the following code:

```
students_list = []

for student in students:

    student_dict = {}

    dict_student['nane'] = name
    logger.info(student_dict['name'])
    # prints ==> MÓNICA MENÉNDEZ GALLEGOS

    dict_student['address'] = address
    logger.info(student_dict['address'])
    # prints ==> GENERAL YAGÜE 32

    students_list.append(dict_student)

logger.info(students_list)
# prints => [{'name':u'M\xd3NICA MEN\xc9NDEZ GALLEGOS', 'address': u'GENERAL YAG\xdcE 32}
```

As you can see, it is a very simple piece of code. I get a value, assign it to a dictionary and append said dict to a list.

The thing that is annoying me is that when I log the value of `student_dict['name']` I can see all the characters properly.

However, when I log the whole list, its data doesn't show properly.

Why is this?

Comment: How did you set your logger handler? did you use the `encoding` parameter?

Comment: I haven't used the `enconding` parameter. I am just using the  `logger.info` method from the TurboGears2 framework.

Comment: Do you mean the repr output you are seeing in  the list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are seeing the [repr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr) representation of the strings in your list:

```
[{'name':u'M\xd3NICA MEN\xc9NDEZ GALLEGOS', 'address': u'GENERAL YAG\xdcE 32}
```

When you print you are seeing the `str` output.

They are both equal unicode strings:

```
In [1]: (l[0]["address"]) 
Out[1]: u'GENERAL YAG\xdcE 32'
In [2]: (l[0]["address"]) == u"GENERAL YAGÜE 32"
Out[2]: True
```

Comment: @Xar, no prob. You're wlcome